# How to use Type converters for complex data type in ROOM library?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

I'm new to the Room library. I have some complex JSON data structure which I would like to store in a Room database, I don't know how to use `TypeConverters` for multiple list of objects.

My Entity classes are as follows:

```kotlin
    // Trying to put all my custom models in a single table
    @Entity(tableName = "myTable")
    data class RaceModelDatabase(
        @PrimaryKey
        val ID: String,
        @Embedded
        val info: CustomModel,
        @Embedded(prefix = "parti")
        val parti: Map<String, UserModelDatabase>,
        @Embedded
        val totalTime: Map<String, TimeDataModel>
    )
    
    // Custom Models which also has Map objects     
    data class CustomModel(
        val name: String,
        val crdate: String
    )
    
    data class UserModelDatabase(
        @Embedded
        val info: CustomModel,
        @Embedded(prefix = "Result_")
        val result: Map<String, CustomModel>
    )
    
    data class TimeDataModel(
        val Start: Long,
        val End: Long
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use TypeAdapter for one of your Map objects. You could follow the same for the rest.

```
class RaceTypeConverter {
    @JvmStatic
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(value: String): Map<String, TimeDataModel > {
       val mapType = object : TypeToken<Map<String, TimeDataModel >>() {}.type
       return Gson().fromJson(value, mapType)
    }

    @TypeConverter 
    @JvmStatic
    fun fromStringMap(map: Map<String, TimeDataModel>): String {
       val gson = Gson()
       return gson.toJson(map)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, When i put @JvmStatic annotation it gave me an error saying "only members in named objects and companion objects can be annotated with '@jvmstatic'", After search i solved it by put it in companion object. Now when i put my typeconverter in my data class, it give me error saying "Annotation is not applicable to targe value parameter"

Comment: @Surendar Okay. May I know for which field it complains "Annotation is not applicable to target value parameter" Please post the full stack trace here.

Comment: I just noticed that you use @Embeded annotation for all the Typecoverted fields. Please remove them and let me know. I don't think @Embedded(prefix = "") will work for Typecoverted fields.

Comment: I've tried removing "@Embeded", still same issue is cmg. I've tried putting "@typeConverter" on Database class itself, there also it is saying TypeConverter not applicable to type class